# How to select comments by date (with a DATETIME) field

Tags: sqlite, date

I have a comments table where I store the date and time the comment was posted, in a DATETIME field. What I'd like to know, is how to pull out all comments for just one day. Obviously, the comments could have been posted at any time during that day.

So far, the best I could come up with was either using `BETWEEN 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:59:59' AND 'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59'`, where both dates are the day I want or `LIKE 'YYYY-MM-DD%'`.

Surely, there's a better way than this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That should have been `BETWEEN 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:59:59' AND 'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59'`. Sorry 'bout dat!

Comment: @CL. Unfortunately, I see no edit button. I presume this has something to do with my rep (or lack thereof).

Comment: @CL. Oh, now I see it! All in gray, making it difficult to spot. Many thanks for that. Must've spent a good 3 or 4 minutes looking for that. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get all the records for just one day you can use date() function in 'where' part of your query, which will serve two purposes:
    - truncate time portion from your datetime records
    - parse 'YYYY-MM-DD' value of your desired day

Here we create a table with 2 records, one timestamped as of January 1st, 2007 and another is timestamped by today datetime. Then we select those two records separately:

```
bash-3.2$ sqlite3 some.db
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table myTable (txt varchar(25), timestamp DATETIME);
sqlite> insert into myTable (txt, timestamp) Values ('asdf',datetime());
sqlite> insert into myTable (txt, timestamp) Values ('asdf-2','2007-01-01 10:00:00');
sqlite> select * from myTable where date(timestamp) = date('2007-01-01');
asdf-2|2007-01-01 10:00:00
sqlite> select * from myTable where date(timestamp) = date(datetime());
asdf|2016-11-17 17:09:15
sqlite>
```

Comment: Aha! I tried wrapping the column name with date, and then the column value. It never occurred to me to wrap the BOTH with date. Thank you ever so much! :)